# Committing "userinterfacestate.xcuserstate" in subversion

Tags: svn, xcode4, commit

According to svnX, there is a file, named "**userinterfacestate.xcuserstate**" which has been changed, I can't see it from within xcode. Should I commit this change? If I don't commit, will it crash other people code when they update with my code?

Answer (score 4):

You can see this file if you right click your project file and choose "Show Package Contents".

I think this is a workspace related file (like .pbxuser & others) and you can simply ignore this in your commits.